# How is method in class template being called?

Tags: javascript

I'm implementing a class template like this:

```
function Class() {
    var _class = function () {
        console.log("init");
        this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    _class.prototype.init = function () { };
    return _class;
}

var Person = new Class;
var person = new Person("alice");
```

and I'm trying to figure out how `_class` is being called. Nothing I can see is calling `init` so why is it executing?

Comment: Oh crap. That makes total sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750082/javascript-oop-best-practices/13074081#13074081

Comment: @BrettWeber you should really provide some context for those links. This is the second time today I've seen you link to your answer from another question with absolutely no information scent.

Comment: I'll keep it in mind, I'm working and looking for information so I haven't spent much time to slow down and explain much.

Comment: @BrettWeber You can make a human readable link in a comment like this: `[Check out this similar answer which may help!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750082/javascript-oop-best-practices/13074081#13074081)` (becomes [Check out this similar answer which may help!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750082/javascript-oop-best-practices/13074081#13074081)).

Comment: AH! that works. Appreciate the tip. Again, hadn't slowed down to think about it. thanks