# Declare function twice for closure?

Tags: javascript, closures, iife

I've got something like this:

```
// This executes once when the page loads.
(function() {
    //under some conditions, it calls:
    myfunction();

    function myFunction() {  
        // defines function
    }
}());

function thisIsCalledByAnOnClick() {
    // HERE I need to call myFunction()
}
```

I dont want `myFunction()` to be called from the console, so I enclosed it inside the anonymous function. So, If I need to call it somewhere else, do I declare it twice or what do I do?

Comment: [You can expose the function outside of the closure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13074081/1257652) to accomplish what you are needing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define thisIsCalledByAnOnclick() within the anonymous function.
2. Assign the onClick handle with addEventListener.

Answer (score 2):

Within the closure `thisIsCalledByAnOnClick` has access to `myFunction`. For further information see: [module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript).

```
// This executes once when the page loads.
var modul = function() {
    //under some conditions, it calls:
    myfunction();

    function myFunction() {
        // defines function
    }

    return {
        thisIsCalledByAnOnClick : function() {
        // HERE I need to call myFunction()
        }
    };
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can usee a constructor function to encapsulate both functions. One as a public function and the other private.

D.

Answer (score 0):

```
function() {
     xyz = function() {
           return this;
           };

     xyz.prototype= {

     Myfunction1 : function(param1,param2)  {
     //some code!!!
     },
     Myfunction2 : function(param1,param2) {
     //some code!!!
     }
     };
})();

function thisIsCalledByAnOnClick() {

        instance=new xyz();
        instance.Myfunction1(a,b)
}
```