# JavaScript OOP reference approach

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning SO, I am moving from the functional programming methodology of JavaScript to the Object Oriented methodology and have a question.  In functional programming I could just call a function within another function example:

```
function a(){
    // do something and when done call function b
    b();
}

function b(){ 
    // does more stuff 
}
```

Now that I am switching to the OOP approach how would I call a method in an object from another method in the same object.  for example:

```
var myClass = function(){
    this.getData = function(){
        //do a jquery load and on success call the next method
        $('#a').load('file.asp',function(response,status,xhr){
            switch(status){
                case "success":
                    //THIS IS WHERE THE QUESTION LIES
                    this.otherfuntcion();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    this.otherfunction = new function(){
        // does more stuff
    }
}

p = new myClass();
p.getData();
```

Can I say this.b() on success to call the method b or do i have to do something else?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Spelling mistake. `this.otherfunction()`

Comment: just as a resource to help you along, too.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13074081/1257652

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be very slow with more methods and a lot of instances. Use prototypes instead:

```
var myClass = function(){

}
myClass.prototype = {
    getData: function(){
        //do a jquery load and on success call the next method
        $('#a').load('file.asp',function(response,status,xhr){
            switch(status){
                case "success":
                    //THIS IS WHERE THE QUESTION LIES
                    this.otherfunction();
                break;
            }
        }.bind(this))
    },
    otherfunction: new function(){
        // does more stuff
    }
};


p = new myClass();
p.getData();
```

Comment: Isn't `this` inside complete callback referring to jqXHR object?

Comment: @inf3rno, apologies ina dvance but I'm new to this style of programming.  Why would prototypes be faster?

Comment: Because it is a core js feature, so it is implemented in your js engine, for example in v8 by chrome.

Comment: It will be faster because all instances of your "class" will share the same memory.

Comment: @inf3rno, I assume then in the main myClass function I can declare variables that can be referenced in all prototypes?  I can just call them by var name in the prototypes correct?

Comment: Yes, if you use the `this` keyword prefix. `this.myVariable = "public";` and `var anotherVariable = "private";`

Comment: If you want to read more about Prototyping in JS I suggest you to read this [article by mozzila](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Comment: Thank you.  I know I have a long road to go but I'm off to a decent start.

Comment: That's not the simplest concept to get your head round, but I can see it's worth it.  Thanks for my "something new" today :)

Comment: I don't think this is the best way of learning oop. I mean there are base concepts like SOLID principles, design patterns or TDD which you can of course learn from experience, but that can take many years. Learning them from a book for example [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882) is a lot faster... I intend to write books in this topic, but first I need to learn how to write English. It is a really hard task... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The `this` context inside your anonymous callback function is different from the one inside the methods of your class. Therefore, you need to keep a reference to your context inside a closure :

```
var that = this;
$('#a').load('file.asp',function(response,status,xhr){
    switch(status){
        case "success":
            //THIS IS WHERE THE QUESTION LIES
            that.otherfuntcion();
        break;
    }
});
```

An alternative would be to bind a specific context to your anonymous function :

```
$('#a').load('file.asp',function(response,status,xhr){
    switch(status){
        case "success":
            //THIS IS WHERE THE QUESTION LIES
            this.otherfuntcion();
        break;
    }
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: We usually call a `bind` to change the scope in these cases, using `that`, `self`, etc... is not recommended for a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

You should copy the outer function context into the new variable to refer directly to the outer context. `this` in the inner function is a context of this *inner* function.

```
var self = this;
$('#a').load('file.asp',function(response,status,xhr){
    switch(status){
        case "success":
            //THIS IS WHERE THE QUESTION LIES
            self.otherfuntcion();
        break;
    }
}
```