# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I dont know why its giving me the Uncaught ReferenceError: predictMove is not defined.
 I want to use predictMove() as an auxiliar function. 
Can you help me please guys?

```
var Crab = extend(Actor, {
        type : "Crab",
        isStuck : false,
        predictMove : function(auxx, auxy) {
            ............

        },
        animation : function() {
            ......... I call the predictMove() function somewhere in this piece of code......

    })
```

Comment: We don't have enough code but you probably don't have the right context (`this`).

Comment: How are you calling `predictMove()`?  Are you doing `this.predictMove()`?  How are you calling `animation()`?  Are you sure `this` is what you think it is?  Are you trying to do `this.predictMove()` inside of a callback?

Comment: this link may help you get a better understanding of scope and how you could set up your object. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13074081/1257652

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function invokations that are giving `undefined error`:

`this.functionName(...); // Important: Add the **this**`

**FYI**: You have a scoping issue.